# multi-tenancy with sequelize and nest.js

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, database-connection, nestjs, multi-tenant

I want to implement a multi-tenant solution where I have one webserver and one database shared across all tenants. Regarding to this [blog post from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/database/multi-tenant-data-isolation-with-postgresql-row-level-security/) it is "pooled multi tenancy model".

I'm using nest.js and sequelize. If sequelize is not a good fit for this I also could switch to another library like typeORM if necessary.

How can this be implemented? I'm absolutely clueless how I can use a different connection (different database user) for each HTTP request and also I don't know how to set a runtime context variable for the connection in a good way.

What I get currently is that every HTTP requests contains a header `tenant-id`. This should be used for all queries.

There is also the concept of [scopes in sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html). But this is something that is implemented on the client side and not on the database directly. Also, this is something that is specific to sequelize. I would prefer a solution that is independent from sequelize and maybe more specific to PostgreSQL.

Is there any way to implement this with sequelize? A hint or a basic approach would be sufficient.

Answer (score -2):

That seems that this approach is similar. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/education/deploy/design-multi-tenant-architecture.
I'm studding for create a similar architecture, but i will use the "silo" model or "physical database". I think that at first you need to create a internal database called "catalog" that will contains the information of the user (this user already have a login? if true select this information) where have to contains a previous credentials how tenant-id. About the Sequelize, i guess that is necessary to use RAW queries for create ROLE|GRANT|DATA BASE etc and the MIGRATIONS to create the same DB for each new clients.

Comment: This isn't a answer to my question at all. How can I implement this with Sequelize? How can I select the database user that should be used (because the referenced blog suggests to usw row level security with a user per tenant)?